# What is the complexity of path compression technique for disjoint set algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find

I was studying the [disjoint algorithm with the union by rank and path compression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find-algorithm-set-2-union-by-rank/).

It is clear to me if `Union by rank` is used then the `find() operation` complexity is `O(log(n))`.

But I wonder what is the `complexity of the path compression technique` for disjoint set algorithm if I use union by rank or not use union by rank?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you link the sets together arbitrarily instead of using union-by-rank or union-by-size, then path compression alone will achieve *O(m log n)* time for any sequence of *n* unions and *m* finds (with m > n).  That makes the *amortized* cost of a find operation *O(log n)*

The proof is difficult, so here's an excellent confirmatory reference: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/lectures/UnionFind.pdf